# Perform Function when Popover is Dismissed

Tags: ios, swift

I have a popover that is using the same view controller that calls it.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "groupSelect" {
        let popVC = segue.destination
        popVC.popoverPresentationController?.delegate = self
    }
}

func adaptivePresentationStyle(for controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
    return UIModalPresentationStyle.none
}
```

However, because I used the storyboard to make everything, I'm not really sure how or where I can take over or add code when the popover gets dismissed. In Xcode 8.2 with Swift 3, adding a popover with the storyboard editor automatically makes the popover dismiss when the user touches outside the popover. Everything is working great, the only problem is that when I return from the popover, the table under it won't have the reload function called so any changes made in the popover don't take effect for the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement `UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate` method `popoverPresentationControllerDidDismissPopover` which tells the delegate that the popover was dismissed.

Comment: That's what I needed, thank you! Is there a good Swift reference that has these methods listed out?

Comment: you're welcome. and you can go to apple documentation  where you can get reference. https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uipopoverpresentationcontrollerdelegate